# RazorEngine with layout : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, razor

I have the following code:

```
public string View(string view, object model)
{
    var template = File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath(@"~\Views\PublishTemplates\" + view + ".cshtml"));
    if (model == null)
    {
        model = new object();
    }
    return RazorEngine.Razor.Parse(template, model);
}
```

and I'm using the following view

```
@model NewsReleaseCreator.Models.NewsRelease
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutBlank.cshtml";
}
@Model.Headline
```

I am getting:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
>      RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateBase.RazorEngine.Templating.ITemplate.Run(ExecuteContext context) in c:\Users\Matthew\Documents\GitHub\RazorEngine\src\Core\RazorEngine.Core\Templating\TemplateBase.cs:139

If I remove the Layout Line it works fine

My Layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    @RenderSection("MetaSection", false)
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @RenderSection("HeaderSection", false)
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not using Razor Engine

My solution does require a controller context so I just use the one from the Controller that was called. So in my controller

```
InstanceOfMyClass.ControllerCurrent = this
```

And in MyClass

```
    public string RenderViewToString(string viewName, object model, string layoutName)
    {
        ControllerCurrent.ViewData.Model = model;
        try
        {
            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(ControllerCurrent.ControllerContext, viewName, layoutName);
                ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerCurrent.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ControllerCurrent.ViewData, ControllerCurrent.TempData, sw);
                viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
                return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I looked sources of TemplateBase.cs (https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/blob/master/src/Core/RazorEngine.Core/Templating/TemplateBase.cs):

```
line 139:    return layout.Run(context);
```

NullReferenceException possibe, if 'layout' variable is null. Ok, what is 'layout'?

```
line 133: var layout = ResolveLayout(Layout);
```

Go deeper (https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/blob/master/src/Core/RazorEngine.Core/Templating/TemplateService.cs):

```
public ITemplate Resolve(string cacheName, object model)
{
    CachedTemplateItem cachedItem;
    ITemplate instance = null;
    if (_cache.TryGetValue(cacheName, out cachedItem))
        instance = CreateTemplate(null, cachedItem.TemplateType, model);

    if (instance == null && _config.Resolver != null)
    {
        string template = _config.Resolver.Resolve(cacheName);
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(template))
            instance = GetTemplate(template, model, cacheName);
    }

    return instance;
}
```

And, i see here, that NullReference is possible, if _config.Resolver is null. Check your Resolver.

Comment: Not sure what a resolver is but I probably missed something obvious

Comment: My eventual solution was to not use razor engine. I'll post my answer now